# How to do commulative addition with respect to certain text in excel 2013?

Tags: excel-2013

I want to calculate commulative sum w.r.t to certain text and show that commulative sum in front of the text as shown in figure attached. Is there any simpler way to do it without IFs?

[Figure](http://s12.postimg.org/3yqwgozwd/ssss.png)

Comment: Please show how you are doing it now (with IFs)

Comment: =IF(A5=A2,B2+1,0)
And it becomes nasty as we move along the columns. .!!
@George

Answer (score 0):

Use one column where you run a cumulative count of all "A"s you see. Another column where you run a cumulative count of all "B"s you see, etc. The formulas for each column are easy and repeatable. For example, for column B you'll have formulas

```
=IF($A2="A",B1+1,0)
=IF($A3="A",B2+1,0)
=IF($A4="A",B3+1,0)
...
```

Same for other columns.

Once these counts are constructed, you can use them to create a column with the same results you have now. The formula for that would be an `IF` that looks at the value in column A and picks the value from one of the other columns.